# Setting up logging with spring mvc, want to restrict trace/debug to my code only

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

I finally got log4j setup with spring mvc, my log4j properties looks like:

```
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=trace, stdout
```

Now I don't want to see any output except from my own code, is there a way to restrict all log messages to a specific namespace?

When I go into production, I don't want any trace/debug information logged, I guess I have to create a file appender but how would I go about restricting the log messages to only severe type log messages like in a try/catch or something unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example (using a `ConsoleAppeneder`, but same difference):

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.your.package.to.debug=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop=DEBUG
```

This logs at the `INFO` level by default, except for the `your.package.to.debug` and spring-aop packages, logged at the `DEBUG` level. Mix and match levels and packages however required.

I'd be wary of not putting `INFO` into production unless you never need to debug anything, though--particularly during startup, `INFO` is really important. It can also be used to provide general system information.

Also, the `%L` pattern is pretty slow. Fine for rare `WARNING`/etc. logs, not so much for normal operational logging.

Comment: basically I want to display any log that I manually put in my own code, so instead of DEBUG do I use All?  (or is it ALL)

Comment: @Blankman You could, but a `DEBUG` level will show `DEBUG` *and above* levels, including `INFO`, `WARNING`, etc.

Comment: thanks man!  so your saying for production, I create a file appender, and ten put INFO only? is that the best practise? so in my try/catch I put logger.error("...") ?

Comment: @Blankman Yep, in prod, you'd generally remove `DEBUG` levels, set the default to `INFO`. What level to log exceptions at depends on the exception and how serious it is, `WARN` is typical, but it really depends on context. You may also choose to remove some `INFO`-level logging if something logs too much at that level (the same goes for all levels, though).